# Is possible to compare two density distributions 'trends'?

Tags: distributions, density-function, density-estimation

I have responses from two groups (A and B) on a confidence rating about a distance judgment task. The participants saw pairs of stimuli and after they were asked to rate their confidence about the distance between the two stimuli. Responses were recorded using a slider from "sure near" (left anchor) to "sure far" (right anchor) where the middle point represented the "I don't know". The slider recorded values from 0 (sure near) to 100 (sure far) by 1.

I would like to compare density distributions of this confidence rating (0–100) between A and B. In addition to the area under the curve of regions of the density distributions (and the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test), is there a way to compare the density 'trends' between the two groups? I would like to have a parameter (or a statistical test) that could express how certainty judgments in the two groups differentiate themselves based on frequency trends (i.e., the shape of the distribution) and then with that parameter perform a statistical test (e.g., t-test to compare A and B)?

I am using R for the analyses if you have codes or functions suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to CV, atnplab. I feel your question could be clarified. How are you using "area under the curve" in your question?  The area under probability distributions is 1, yes? Does "density 'trends'" just mean cumulative distribution, or something else? Finally, "shape of the distribution" does not imply a single kind of difference (e.g., flat versus tall): what aspects of shape are important to you (especially what do you mean by "frequency trends").

Comment: Hi @Alexis! Thanks for your comment..I would like to use AUC to compare for instance if each individual in the 2 groups has more responses under a particular section of the density plot. By density/frequency trends I mean the actual trend of the line of a density plot, I could have individuals with steep distributions around a particular section of the x-axis but other having a more smooth distribution along the x-axis. I want to compare, for instance, these two patterns, to see if individuals in the two groups are more confident (more frequencies around particular values) or viceversa

Comment: It would be nice to see two estimated smooth density plots, overlaid on the same set of axes.